# Apache environment variable

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, environment-variables

Im trying to add some environment variables to apache centos 8.
Usually those are simply added to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` on previous centos versions (mainly centos 7); but this directory is not present on this centos version.

I tried adding the file myself but it doesnt seem apache is reading from there.

How can I add apache environment variables on centos 8.

Answer (score 2):

With CentOS 8, the environment variables of your Apache server are handled by `systemd`.

See the content of the `httpd` service:

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
```

> To customize the behaviour, run "systemctl edit httpd" to create an override unit.
> [...] enter the following:
>
> [Service]
> Environment=OPTIONS=-DMY_DEFINE

So you have to create an override with the command `sudo systemctl edit httpd`, add your environments variables in it, and restart the service (i.e. `sudo service httpd restart`).

For example:

```
[Service]
Environment=APP_ENV=production LANG=C MY_ENV_VAR=my_value
```

Note that these environment variables will apply to the `httpd` process only, not the `apache` user.